# Rust can't use trait const in trait function

Tags: rust

So I try to define a trait that has a constant and uses that constant in the function 'header', but it gives me an error that there is no such associated constant.

Code:

```
trait SizedBuffer {   
    const SIZE: usize;
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8; Self::SIZE]);
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8; Self::SIZE]);
}

fn main() {
    println!("It compiled!");
}
```

Expected result:

```
It compiled!
```

Instead I got:

```
error[E0599]: no associated item named `SIZE` found for type `Self` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:3:45
  |
3 |     fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8; Self::SIZE]);
  |                                             ^^^^ associated item not found in `Self`
  |
  = help: items from traits can only be used if the type parameter is bounded by the trait
help: the following trait defines an item `SIZE`, perhaps you need to restrict type parameter `Self` with it:
  |
1 | Self: SizedBuffer
  |

error[E0599]: no associated item named `SIZE` found for type `Self` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:4:42
  |
4 |     fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8; Self::SIZE]);
  |                                          ^^^^ associated item not found in `Self`
  |
  = help: items from traits can only be used if the type parameter is bounded by the trait
help: the following trait defines an item `SIZE`, perhaps you need to restrict type parameter `Self` with it:
  |
1 | Self: SizedBuffer
  |

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `trait_const`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```